# Add a custom property to IdentityUserClaim AspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Task:
I have a set of claims (A, B, C), a claim is added to the user, locally or fetched from a third party identity system. I need to track the source. A user can have claims from both sources (local, remote).

My approach to solving this:

I added a custom property to IdentityUserClaim. It seems to be working, but when I try to get or set a claim using userManager I couldn't find the new property.

```
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string> {       
    public bool LocalClaim { get; set; }
    }
```

like

```
 var claim = userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
```

The claim is System.Security.Claims.Claim type.
I want to get the custom property for the given claim.

```
await userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);
```

Requirement

Comment: Can you clarify more about the actual scenario that requires add this custom property in IdentityUserClaim? so that we can understand the requirement better.

Comment: @FeiHan added the task in question. Thanks